# Java 8 Stream - Why is filter method not executing?

Tags: java, filter, java-8, stream, java-stream

I am learning filtering using java stream.
But the stream after filtering is not printing anything.
I think the filter method is not getting executed.
My filtering code is as follows:

```
Stream.of("d2", "a2", "b1", "b3", "c")
    .filter(s -> {
        s.startsWith("b");
        System.out.println("filter: " + s);
        return true;
    });
```

There is no compilation error and no exception also.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`filter` is an intermediate operation, which will be executed only if the Stream pipeline ends in a terminal operation.

For example :

```
Stream.of("d2", "a2", "b1", "b3", "c")
  .filter(s -> {
        s.startsWith("b");
        System.out.println("filter: " + s);
        return true;
  })
  .forEach (System.out::println);
```

As it is, your filter method is useless, since it always returns `true`, and thus performs no filtering.

Comment: Right answer that it needs a terminal operation, thanks. But the fact that it always returns true doesn't stop it from executing.

Comment: @DovevHefetz I never said "the fact that it always returns true stops it from executing". The last sentence is just an observation that this filter is pointless, since all elements pass.