# Java 8 Stream - Execution criteria for sorted method working differently from filter and map method

Tags: java, filter, java-8, stream, java-stream

This question is somhow related to [Java 8 Stream - Filter and foreach method not printing as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40863739/java-8-stream-filter-and-foreach-method-not-printing-as-expected/40864004#40864004)

I am working with sorted, filter and map method of Java 8 Stream.
Keeping in mind how filter and map works as specified in the answers of above mentioned question, I tried the sorted method as follows:

```
Stream.of("d2", "a2", "b1", "b3", "c")
.sorted((s1, s2) -> {
    System.out.printf("sort: %s; %s\n", s1, s2);
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
})
.filter(s -> {
    System.out.println("filter: " + s);
    return s.startsWith("a");
})
.map(s -> {
    System.out.println("map: " + s);
    return s.toUpperCase();
})
.forEach(s -> System.out.println("forEach: " + s));
```

And the output i got is:

> sort:    a2; d2
>   sort:    b1; a2
>   sort:    b1; d2
>   sort:    b1; a2
>   sort:    b3; b1
>   sort:    b3; d2
>   sort:    c; b3
>   sort:    c; d2
>   filter:  a2
>   map:     a2
>   forEach: A2
>   filter:  b1
>   filter:  b3
>   filter:  c
>   filter:  d2

That is, now the sorted method is executed for the complete loop and then filter and map functions are executed on individual items.
As all the three are intermediate functions, so all should have worked the same manner. 
Is the execution order fine or not? I am not getting what i am doing wrong.

Comment: How can you sort the elements, without all of seeing them? Same as `distinct()`. It is still lazy -- the `sorted` operation would not be invoked if `forEach` weren't there.

Comment: @KaranVerma you should really stop asking so many questions and read a few things.

Comment: the stream pipeline could completely eliminate the sorting here since forEach is an unordered terminal op. i think it used to do just that in previous versions but that optimization was removed because it sometimes was applied to aggressively

Comment: [*Stateful operations may need to process the entire input before producing a result. For example, one cannot produce any results from sorting a stream until one has seen all elements of the stream*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). Yes, it’s the same link that answers [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40863739/2711488) and [the question you asked before that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40862906/2711488). The magic thing that answers all of your questions is called *the official documentation*.

Comment: @the8472: ironically, that’s what it never did, despite being too aggressive in the past. It has been said, that it is unlikely to do that in future versions either, as the combination of `sorted` and an unordered terminal operation is likely to be a usage error that has no correct behavior (and why optimizing an erroneous case). So using that in a parallel stream ends up wasting time sorting while still calling the consumer in arbitrary order…

Comment: @Holger it's conceivable that a stream producer sorts by default but some far removed consumer doesn't care about order so it would be a useful optimization imo.

Comment: @the8472: I don’t see the value in “sorting by default”. If a consumer is interested in a sorted result, (s)he can chain a sort op. Having to opt out for not wasting resources doesn’t sound like a good pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

> **Side-effects**
>
> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.
>
> [...] Further, the ordering of those effects may be surprising. Even when a pipeline is constrained to produce a result that is consistent with the encounter order of the stream source (for example, `IntStream.range(0,5).parallel().map(x -> x*2).toArray() must produce [0, 2, 4, 6, 8])`, no guarantees are made as to the order in which the mapper function is applied to individual elements, or in what thread any behavioral parameter is executed for a given element.

[image]

Comment: that image... it's both funny and weird

Answer (score 3):

"it depends". Stream operations can interleave because each stage can emit items as soon as their order is evident. In the case of filtering and mapping, each item can be processed and swallowed or passed.

In the case of sorting, it all depends on the sorting algorithm. If the sorting was implementing as "find the minimum of all elements with n-1 comparisons, emit the minimum, repeat with the rest", the sorting would indeed interleave with the filtering and mapping. But looking at your output, it looks more like an insertion sort (with binary search or some search tree for the insertion point): a2/d2 are compared resulting (a2, d2); b1 is compared to a2 first and then d2 to insert it between the two yielding (a2,b1,d2), b3 is compared to b1, then d2 and inserted to (a2,b1,b3,d2) and so on.
This makes sense as it yields an expected O(nlogn) time for sorting (compared to O(n^2) for the repeated minimum finding), but it cannot emit anything until the last element is inserted.
That is, sorting must complete before filtering can start.

Comment: Oh, to clarify my answer: You're not doing anything wrong. My answer should help you to accept and understand why your output is perfectly reasonable.